# In Clojure, how to check if an object is a core.async channel?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

There is a function `chan` to create a channel. But I don't see a `chan?`.
How would I write a predicate `chan?` that returns true for objects created by `chan`?

I'm asking about both Clojure and ClojureScript.

Comment: There is an open issue that you can vote on in JIRA: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/ASYNC-74.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since channels are [implemented as](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/2afc2dc5102f60713135ffca6fab993fb35809f0/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async/impl/channels.clj):

```
(deftype ManyToManyChannel [^LinkedList takes ^LinkedList puts ^Queue buf closed ^Lock mutex add!]
   ...)
```

You can just check if it's an instance of `ManyToManyChannel`:

```
(import [clojure.core.async.impl.channels ManyToManyChannel])

(instance? ManyToManyChannel obj)
```

Or, if you care more about the protocols rather than the type itself, you can check if the object `satisfies?` one the the protocols:

```
(satisfies? clojure.core.async.impl.protocols/WritePort
            obj)
```

Comment: @RobN I should note that I don't know Clojurescript. I quick search though shows that `import` seems to work differently between clj and cljs. I know this works for the former; not sure about the latter.

Comment: Strongly prefer the `instance? ManyToManyChannel` solution if you will be calling this frequently as it is roughly 10,000 times faster than the `satisfies? ...` solution, ~4 nanoseconds vs ~40 microseconds on my machine. I discovered this after a frenzied quest to discover why my program was running half as fast (used this ~4 times in an important inner function). Avoid my fate ;-)